# Is there a way to conditionally set the value of an aggregate in Oracle 12c?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

I'm looking to setup a query that would populate a column from a GROUP BY query based on whether the field has a specify value in the grouping. I'm working in Oracle 12c.

Sample Table:

```
uname    event   tstamp
------  ------  ----------------------
user1   3       10-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
user1   9       14-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
user1   32       14-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user1   21      20-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user1   8       23-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user2   9       14-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user2   8       23-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user2   3       05-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
user3   15      06-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user3   1       30-AUG-19 11.00.00 AM
user3   7       14-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
```

I would like the query to output:

```
uname    event   tstamp
------  ------  ---------------------
user1   21      14-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
user2   8       05-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
user3   7       14-SEP-19 11.00.00 AM
```

I was looking for a query that worked something like this:

```
select uname, SomeAggregate(if contains 21 then 21 else DoesNotMatter) event, max(tstamp)
from table
group by uname
```

Comment: According to your pseudo-code, it doesn't matter what value is returned if there are no 21's.  Would you be equally happy if the `user2` and `user3` rows returned NULL?  Or does it need to return one of the values associated with the user?  In your sample output, the `tstamp` for `user2` is Aug 23 when there is a later Sept 5 row.  Is that intentional?

Comment: I've corrected the tstamp issue. The tstamp returned needs to be the latest date in the grouping. A NULL in the event column might be OK and if it is not then I could just use NVL().

Comment: Why does user1 have 23-aug-19? Its MAX date is 14-sep-19.

Comment: @Littlefoot, thanks I've corrected that too. It is supposed to return the latest date in the grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way, maybe a little shorter than others:

```
select uname, 
       coalesce(max(case when event = 21 then event else null end), max(event)) event, 
       max(tstamp) 
          keep ( dense_rank first order by case when event = 21 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END asc,
                                           event desc ) tstamp 
from test
group by uname;
```

Comment: what does the KEEP function do? I've run the query with just max(tstamp) and that works.

Comment: It makes sure that the `tstamp` value shown is the one that matches the row that had the `event` value shown.

Comment: According to the post the max tstamp isnt related to the event filter.

Answer (score 2):

CASE will return 21 if any 21 and NULL for everything else. Then max will either return 21 or null

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/566d38/2)**

```
SELECT "uname"
      , MAX( CASE WHEN "event" = 21 THEN "event" END) as "event"
      , MAX( "tstamp" ) as "tstamp" 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "uname"
ORDER BY "uname";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| uname |  event |                tstamp |
|-------|--------|-----------------------|
| user1 |     21 | 2019-09-14 11:00:00.0 |
| user2 | (null) | 2019-09-05 11:00:00.0 |
| user3 | (null) | 2019-09-14 11:00:00.0 |
```

Comment: I've update the sample data. The specific value might not be the max value in the column.

Comment: In your data the 21 isn't the same as max tstamp value either.

Comment: I got the same output as you request only I leave the null because you said value doesnt matter.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SQL> with test (uname, event, tstamp) as
  2    (select 'user1', 3,  date '2019-09-10' from dual union all
  3     select 'user1', 9,  date '2019-09-14' from dual union all
  4     select 'user1', 32, date '2019-08-14' from dual union all
  5     select 'user1', 21, date '2019-08-20' from dual union all
  6     select 'user1', 8,  date '2019-08-23' from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 'user2', 3, date '2019-09-05'  from dual union all
  9     select 'user2', 9, date '2019-08-14'  from dual union all
 10     select 'user2', 8, date '2019-08-23'  from dual union all
 11     --
 12     select 'user3', 15, date '2019-08-06' from dual union all
 13     select 'user3', 1,  date '2019-08-30' from dual union all
 14     select 'user3', 7,  date '2019-09-14' from dual
 15    )
 16  select t.uname,
 17         max(case when (select max(1) from test t1
 18                        where t1.uname = t.uname
 19                          and t1.event = 21
 20                       ) = 1 then 21
 21                  else t.event
 22             end) event,
 23         max(t.tstamp) tstamp
 24  from test t
 25  group by t.uname
 26  order by t.uname;

UNAME      EVENT TSTAMP
----- ---------- ----------------
user1         21 2019-09-14 00:00
user2          9 2019-09-05 00:00
user3         15 2019-09-14 00:00

SQL>
```

If there's `event = 21`, it'll be returned. If not, the `MAX` event will be returned (which is as good as any other value, as you said that you don't actually care), along with `MAX` `tstamp` for each `uname`.

Comment: I've update the sample data. The specific value might not be the max value in the column.

Comment: The way you put it, you need `MAX(tstamp)` for each of them, along with event 21 (if it exists) or any other if 21 doesn't exist. If that's so, then query gets quite simple - edited.

Comment: Your logic is wrong if event are  21 and 22, MAX() will be 22 and that isn't what OP want. In your sample you omit the 32 on original sample

Comment: There was no "32" until the last edit, @Juan - but yes, my previous attempt returned wrong result anyway if there was event higher than 21. Now it is fixed (but looks ugly).

Answer (score 1):

This is another short version:

```
select uname,
  nvl(max(case event when 21 then 21 end), max(event)) event,
  nvl(max(case event when 21 then tstamp end), min(tstamp)) tstamp
from test
group by uname;
```

Demo on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/FMJ71407).